# jQuery Ui draggable is slow on IE 11

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-11, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

My page contains 2 trees and we had to enable drag/drop between them.
Those trees have a lot of items (> 150), and this causes a huge slowdown on IE11.

The slowdown happens between the `start` and `drag` events, and we're talking about a 3 seconds delay (105ms on Chrome). This means that the actual drag starts 3 seconds after the `mousedown` on the item, making the user experience quite bad.

I started investigating jQuery Ui's source code, and I found out that commenting [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/draggable.js#L220) makes the delay drop to 100ms (4 on Chrome, we probably need to comment some other lines to completely fix IE).

Basically, what happens is that IE takes a lot of time to run `$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets( this, event );` for some reasons, and we couldn't find a way to fix it besides changing jQuery Ui's code.

So, the question is: is there a way to achieve the same result (aka a good response time for the drag on IE11) without having to change the code of an external library that might be updated somewhere in the future?

Comment: Can you add your CSS/HTML/Javascript here and a link to a jsbin.com or equivalent. I have a web app mostly used in ie11 using jQuery drag and drop that works pretty well (can easily have 150 draggable div's at a time).